# Is there a clear way of initializing a loop that is terminated when a number is entered as a String?

Tags: java, string, loops

So it's been about 6 months since I've done anything with coding as well as I'm still relatively new to it. I'm doing some review and the program asks for several attributes, in which one is a string asking for an employee's ID #. It is supposed be in a loop, in which the loop is terminated when the user enters 0 for their employee ID. I have the program working up until this point and I haven't created the loop yet which is where I am stuck.

```
`import java.util.Scanner;`
`public class PayrollTester {`
  `public static void main(String[] args) {`
    `String empID;`
    `float gross;`
    `float ste;`
    `float fed;`
    `Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);`
    `System.out.println("Enter your Employee ID: ");`
    `empID = scnr.nextLine();`
    `System.out.println("Enter your Gross Pay: ");`
    `gross = scnr.nextFloat();`
    `System.out.println("Enter your State Tax Rate: ");`
    `ste = scnr.nextFloat();`
    `System.out.println("Enter your Federal Tax Rate: ");`
    `fed = scnr.nextFloat();`

    `Payroll empID1 = new Payroll(empID, gross, ste, fed);`



   `System.out.println("The Net Pay for Employee " + 
    empID1.getEmplyeID() + " is " + empID1.calcNetPay());`
 `}`
`}`
```

Comment: Where do you need to use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a while(true) loop and then you have an if statement right after they enter their employee id that checks to see if the value they entered is equal to 0.

```
while(true){
    //get their employee id
    

    if (empiID.equals("0")){
        break;
    }

    //get more user inputs
}
```

Comment: So that somewhat solved my issue, now the problem is after the program displays the Net Pay, it doesn't ask for the employee ID again but instead goes straight to asking for the Gross Pay. How do I get it to loop back to the employee ID?

Comment: Chances are you are asking for the employee ID outside of the loop. Make sure it is in the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I got it to work.